# AWS - Multiple S3 bucket for multiple subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I made my research, but I cannot find a specific example for this.

I have my main domain: domain.com. It works well with S3 - cloudfront - cert. manager setup, but I would like to create multiple subdomains for individual s3 buckets.

My goal:

Main: domain.com

subdomain1: landing1.domain.com -> S3 landing1 bucket.
subdomain2: landing2.domain.com -> S3 landing2 bucket.

Overall plan is to use one general domain but I will have several static pages for different topics.

Can it work? How can I setup this? Any example/flow explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. I'm using this setup in production. Let me explain my set up.
Lets say I have three different subdomains; one.example.com, two.example.com, three.example.com.
I have created three different CloudFront distribution for each of them. Attach the same ACM certificate for each of them on CloudFront.
Finally, I directed them via Route53.

```
one.example.com -> one.cloudfront.net
two.example.com -> two.cloudfront.net
three.example.com -> three.cloudfront.net
```

It works with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned static pages so I assume you just want to host simple html site. If not, the following will not apply.

You need to setup so that the bucket name is same as the intended access URL.

So bucket name for `https://landing1.domain.com` should be `landing1.domain.com`
and `https://landing2.domain.com` should be `landing2.domain.com`.

Make sure Static Web Hosting and public access are turned on for these buckets.

You will not need CloudFront. So this setup is simpler. If you still want to use CloudFront , it is also possible, just setup two separate CloudFront distributions with custom `CNAME`.